# Publishing to one Azure App Service resets the software stack configuration of another app service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I have 3 Azure App Services in one App Service Plan. For two of them I have configured the stack to be .NET Core 3.1, and for the other I have set the stack to be Node js.

Whenever I publish one of the .NET Core applications from Visual studio, the configuration of the one app service that has the Node js application is reset so that the stack there becomes .NET Core also.

The application seems to get deployed correctly, and everything seems to function as expected. The only issue I'm experiencing is that I have to go to the portal to reset the stack of this one app service back to Node.

Any idea what might be going on here?

Update:
I am using the latest version of Visual Studio: 16.4.3

Comment: seems to be a bug. Can you provide the visual studio version your using? Can you perform a the same test using VS Code (for the node app only) and see if it results in the same error?

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio I have updated my answer to include the version of Visual Studio. For the node app, I use FTPS to deploy it, this doesn't alter the app service configuration.